# Raspberry Pi live video streaming with Flask App works with default development server but not in Apache production

Tags: python, apache, flask, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I've hosted a simple Flask App on Apache webserver on a Raspberry Pi to stream real-time video from the PiCamera using tutorial from https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask . Everything works fine locally for me and I can access my http://localip:5000 to get my live video feed. I now wanted to host this on a production server and I used Apache. I set all the configuration files and directory structures linked my Flask app and set the server for port 80. I visit the http://ip:80 and my webpage loads with a title, heading and static text but the video that is supposed to be below it is now a picture of a "broken image". Inspecting the webpage video element on the browser shows that the server returned nothing.

I saw another post [Video Straming on raspberrypi using flask apche2and wsgi server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768567/video-straming-on-raspberrypi-using-flask-apche2and-wsgi-server), of a guy who ran into the same problem as mine. He marked an answer saying Apache wasn't having root access to the picamera and hence wasn't able to access it. I know that Apache runs as www-data group user and I don't know which folder/file I should give permissions so that it can access the PiCamera. I don't know how to go about from here.Locally using the inbuild flask dev web server everything is working perfectly but on serving through Apache the camera isn't capturing the images. Please help me. Here is my basic code and configurations (Flask app name is VideoStream):

**VideoStream.wsgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/VideoStream/")

from VideoStream import app as application
```

**Apache Configuration file:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName 10.0.0.69
                ServerAdmin realityreccode@gmail.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/VideoStream/VideoStream.wsgi
                WSGIDaemonProcess VideoStream user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 home=/var/www/VideoStream/
        <Directory /var/www/VideoStream/VideoStream/>
                WSGIProcessGroup VideoStream
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                WSGIScriptReloading On
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/VideoStream-error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/VideoStream-access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

**Directory Structure:**

```
/var/www/VideoStream/
VideoStream.wsgi
VideoStream/
    __init__.py
    camera_pi.py
    base_camera.py
    templates/index.html
```

**__init__.py - Flask app :**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from importlib import import_module
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from VideoStream.camera_pi import Camera


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('index.html')
def gen(camera):

while True:
    frame = camera.get_frame()
    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
           b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():

    return Response(gen(Camera()),
                mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='10.0.0.69', threaded=True, debug=True)
```

Comment: Did you try to run your scripting `sudo`?

Comment: For running the flask app and using the inbuilt default server I use `sudo python3 __init__.py` and everything is fine. But my problem is when I do the same over Apache. After making changes I just `sudo service apache2 restart` and I guess Apache just serves automatically after that. Where can I use the `sudo` command for giving Apache access?

Comment: Also I'm using the RaspiCam which connects to a dedicated CSI interface because of which I do not get a /dev/video0. The RaspiCam has to be access Pythonically is what is said here https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=68247

Comment: What the error log or access log shown? What groups that www-data belonging to (try `groups www-data`)?

Comment: @hcheung Thank you for your help. I've found what the problem was. I changed logging by `LogLevel warn` in WSGI config and saw that the camera thread was not starting. So I checked the user groups like you said and added www-data to video user group and the camera thread starts successfully.